# Count of KPI from different tables based on date

Tags: powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have the following 4 tables and i want to show the count of ID's for each KPI's for each Caseload (1,2,3,4 etc ) something like in the second picture.

I am not sure what is the correct method but i've created a date table and use as slicer because one iD might be in a all 4 table but the KPI*Date might be different.

Any ideeas how to calculate this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For me isn't clear what you want to achieve. Add some examples with dummy data (source table), and desired output.